# How to sum all values in a df column (col1) where three other column (col2,col3,col4) match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have four columns in my df:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

and I want to get to this df:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

by summing col1 values when the other three columns are all the same.

Edit:
I tried

```
df = df.groupby(["col2","col3","col4"]).col1.sum()
```

but `print(df)` clearly shows those columns not summed. Is it possible I should try to force the column to a type first?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `df.groupby(['col2','col3','col4']).sum()`? and *didn't seem to work* is not a good start. What goes wrong with that piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by ALL columns, then use [`.agg()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-agg/#:%7E:text=Pandas%20Series.agg%20%28%29%20is%20used%20to%20pass%20a,multiple%20results%20are%20returned%20by%20agg%20%28%29%20method.) to only sum Col1:

```
df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], as_index=False).agg({'Col1':'sum'})

   Col2  Col3  Col4  Col1
0     0     0     1     2
1     0     0     1     5
2     1     0     0     6
```

(Please note the columns are now in a different order. You can re-arrange them if necessary)